# Running plex as a docker container, cannot access web UI

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, plex

I am trying to set up my Plex server using docker. I have followed the steps on the [LinuxServer.io](https://linuxserver.io/) docker page. When I run the docker command, it says that it is running find and I get no errors. However, when I try to access the web UI through `localhost:32400/web`, all I get is "Problem loading page"

I am using docker for windows with Linux containers.

**docker command:**

```
docker run -d --name=plex --net=host -e PUID=1000 -e PGID=1000 -e TZ=Europe/London -e VERSION=docker -v D:\plex\config:/config -v D:\media\tvseries:/data/tvshows -v D:\media\movies:/data/movies -v D:\media\transcode:/transcode --restart unless-stopped linuxserver/plex
```

when I use `docker ps` the plex container looks like it is running.

I am new to docker. I have looked around and cannot find why I cannot access the UI.

Please me know if you require additional information.

**docker inspect:**

```
"NetworkMode": "host",
"PortBindings": {
    "32400/tcp": [
        {
            "HostIp": "",
            "HostPort": "32400"
        }
    ]
},
```

please let me know if you require more information

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`--net=host` not work for `docker-for-windows`.

**Reasons:**

Linux container need to share a linux host' kernel.

In order to achieve this, when docker for windows run a linux container, it will had to setup a hyper-v machine. If you open the Hyper-V manager, you will see a `MobyLinuxVM` running.

So, when you use `--net=host`, the container will just use the network of `MobyLinuxVM`, not the windows. So, `localhost` will not work.

**Suggestion:**

For your scenario, I suggest you to remove `--net=host`, add port mapping in command line:

```
docker run -d --name=plex -p 32400:32400 -e PUID=1000 -e PGID=1000 -e TZ=Europe/London -e VERSION=docker -v D:\plex\config:/config -v D:\media\tvseries:/data/tvshows -v D:\media\movies:/data/movies -v D:\media\transcode:/transcode --restart unless-stopped linuxserver/plex
```

Then, magic will happen here, docker for windows will map the windows's 32400 port to your container using windows route mechanism. And you can visit container's service from windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem when I used the docker-compose file provided [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/plex) on docker for windows. Based on the previous answer, I removed the `network_mode: host` entry from the file and I ran  `docker compose up -d` command from the same directory that has the `docker-compose.yml` file, it started fine.

Then I was able to use the host IP (my windows machine IP address) as well as the localhost with no problem as the following

`http://<machine-ip i.e. hostip>:32400/web`
or
`http://localhost:32400/web`

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  plex:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/plex:latest
    container_name: plex
    ports:
      - 32400:32400/tcp
    environment:
      - TZ=Africa/Cairo
      - VERSION=docker
    hostname: aimediaserver
    volumes:
      - F:\Media\config:/config
      - F:\Media\TV:/tv
      - F:\Media\Movies:/movies
    restart: unless-stopped
```